# WMS not displayed in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: geoserver, wms, arcgis-online, extents

I tried to access the WMS request through the ArcGIS Online which is published in geoserver. The WMTS request of the same data is coming fine without any issues. When i checked the geoserver log i'm getting a error like "could not reduce the grid geometry inside the valid area bounds".

The below screenshot shows the details of the error.

[image]

```
2019 -04-03 12 :27 :32, 759 ARN  [lite.gridcoverage2d]  - Could  not  reduce the grid  geometry  inside the valid  area  bounds :
Referenced Envelope [ - 53.0  :  37 .0, -85 .0  :  85.0]
Grid geometry isGridGeometry2D [Grid Envelope2D[1..2074, 0..1007],PARAM_MT["Affine", 
PARAMETER ["num_row" , 3],
PARAMETER ["num_col", 3],
PARAMETER ["elt_0_0", 0 . 25],
PARAMETER ["elt_0_2", 702634 .125], 
PARAMETER ["elt_1_1", -0 .25 ],
PARAMETER ["elt_1_2", 730837.625]]]
```

Comment: Can you copy the error text instead of display an image of it ?

Comment: Sure sir, i have added the error in text